# Radius of "viewable" region in google maps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to know how to retrieve the radius of the viewable zoom level in google maps API v3.

For example, if I am at zoom level 3, and depending on the users screen size (lets just say 400x400 viewable region) how do I get the "radius" circle of the viewable area.

Alternatively I'm currently using map.fitBounds() for all the points I've added to the map so really all I *NEED* is the radius of all the bounds.  What I want is something like "20 miles" that I can feed into my database app.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The radius would equal the distance from the center of the bounds to one of the bound's corners. Using the Great Circle Distance Formula from [the calculations from this page](http://www.meridianworlddata.com/Distance-Calculation.asp), I came up with the following:

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();

var center = bounds.getCenter();
var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();

// r = radius of the earth in statute miles
var r = 3963.0;  

// Convert lat or lng from decimal degrees into radians (divide by 57.2958)
var lat1 = center.lat() / 57.2958; 
var lon1 = center.lng() / 57.2958;
var lat2 = ne.lat() / 57.2958;
var lon2 = ne.lng() / 57.2958;

// distance = circle radius from center to Northeast corner of bounds
var dis = r * Math.acos(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) + 
  Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lon2 - lon1));
```

After playing some more with this, I've noticed that `map.getBounds()` will contain the full map viewport. But if your [`LatLngBounds`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds) is built by extending to include [`LatLng`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng) points, and then you issue a `map.fitBounds(bounds)`, the api increases the map's viewport a bit so that the `bounds` "box" has some padding.

If you use the map's current viewport, the radius from the center to the corner of the viewport might be a longer radius than you want. Maybe the distance from the viewport center to the middle of the furthest viewport edge. (If the map isn't a perfect square)

Comment: Awesomesauce, just what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: To get this example working, the first 3 lines should be 
`var bounds = map.getBounds();

var center = bounds.getCenter();
var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();`

Comment: This does not work for me. I tried implementing this and I keep getting "Cannot read property 'getCenter' of undefined". Has the 'getBounds' function changed?

Answer (score 32):

Refactored version of [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3527136/447249) above using [*google.maps.geometry.spherical*](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) namespace (make sure you loaded [Geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) to make this work).

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var center = map.getCenter();
if (bounds && center) {
  var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
  // Calculate radius (in meters).
  var radius = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(center, ne);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Helps me a lot to keep places requests low to not reach quota too fast.

Answer (score 9):

I also refactored Eric's answer, mine is as a standalone function, and am returning the result in meters (as needed by the [Places API search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests).

```
function getBoundsRadius(bounds){
  // r = radius of the earth in km
  var r = 6378.8
  // degrees to radians (divide by 57.2958)
  var ne_lat = bounds.getNorthEast().lat() / 57.2958
  var ne_lng = bounds.getNorthEast().lng() / 57.2958
  var c_lat = bounds.getCenter().lat() / 57.2958
  var c_lng = bounds.getCenter().lng() / 57.2958
  // distance = circle radius from center to Northeast corner of bounds
  var r_km = r * Math.acos(
    Math.sin(c_lat) * Math.sin(ne_lat) + 
    Math.cos(c_lat) * Math.cos(ne_lat) * Math.cos(ne_lng - c_lng)
    )
  return r_km *1000 // radius in meters
}
```

Comment: pls add ";" at your line ends, so you can use this also in minified versions

Comment: @kaiser semicolons are optional in JavaScript and aren't needed if the minification software is even halfway decent.

Comment: This is the radius on which some area is considered which is not visible in viewport, bu If I have to find radius of the current view such that circle should only be in current view. What should I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

I believe [Bounds](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds) have the getNorthEast() and getSouthWest() methods, but this would give you a rectangle (which bounds really is) and you could than calculate the distance between those two, etc.
To calculate the circle out of that rectandle might be a bit of work...

Maybe this will help: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/mvcfun.html

and the example: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/mvcfun/step6.html

Comment: As you can, maybe, see this is not the preferred and approved answer.  Don't expect me to keep it up to date ;-)