# Google Maps v3 - Viewable map radius in miles

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

How can I find the proximity of the visible area of my map ?

*All this works and is a post to help others who may be looking.*

This code looks at your Google Map v3 and outputs by var proximity the radius in miles of your current map view.

Make sure in your HTML you have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

as libraries=geometry enables it.

```
// Get Gmap radius / proximity start
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var sw = bounds.getSouthWest(); 
var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();

var proximitymeter = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (sw, ne);
var proximitymiles = proximitymeter * 0.000621371192;
alert(" " + proximitymiles + " Miles Proximity");
var proxmity =  proximitymiles; 
// Get Gmap radius / proximity End
```

I hope it helps someone.

An additional edit ( untested ) which allows for screen rotation follows:

```
    // Get Gmap radius / proximity start
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var sw = bounds.getSouthWest(); 
var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
var se = bounds.getSouthEast(); 
var nw = bounds.getNorthWest();

var proximitymeterswne = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (sw, ne);
var proximitymetersenw = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (se, nw);

if (proximitymeterswne > proximitymetersenw) {proximitymeterswne = proximitymiles}
else {if (proximitymetersenw > proximitymeterswne) {proximitymetersenw = proximitymiles};}; 

var proximitymiles = proximitymeter * 0.000621371192;
alert(" " + proximitymiles + " Miles Proximity");
var proxmity =  proximitymiles; 
// Get Gmap radius / proximity End
```

Another EDIT

```
// Watches for map bounds change - if so - set radius and refresh data Start
function setproximityfrommap() {
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525670/radius-of-viewable-region-in-google-maps-v3
    // Get Gmap radius / proximity start
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    // bounds = map.LatLngBounds();
    //center = new google.maps.LatLng();

    ne = bounds.getNorthEast();    
    center = map.getCenter();

    //var center = map.LatLngBounds.getCenter();
    //var ne = map.LatLngBounds.getNorthEast();

    // r = radius of the earth in statute miles
    var r = 3963.0;

    // Convert lat or lng from decimal degrees into radians (divide by 57.2958)
    var lat1 = center.lat() / 57.2958;
    var lon1 = center.lng() / 57.2958;
    var lat2 = ne.lat() / 57.2958;
    var lon2 = ne.lng() / 57.2958;

    // distance = circle radius from center to Northeast corner of bounds
    proximity = r * Math.acos(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lon2 - lon1));
    $('#proximity').val(proximity);
    // Get Gmap radius / proximity End
};
```

---

I put the edited code in the first post.

Terran

Comment: +1 I like your generous approach! But, to stay on the Q&A style of the site, I suggest you to post the goal in the question and the solution as an answer and then accept it (even if it's yours). Thanks ;)

Comment: Thanks - I will do - Wasnt sure what the eticate was ;)

Comment: I could do with adding a check using other corners as this is for an app on a phone which could be turned around ( orientation wise ) as well. Based on readings taking the biggest number as the proximity to use.

Comment: I've not tested this but....  var se = bounds.getSouthEast(); 
    var nw = bounds.getNorthWest();
 
 var proximitymeterswne = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (sw, ne);
 var proximitymetersenw = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (se, nw);
 
 if (proximitymeterswne > proximitymetersenw) {proximitymeterswne = proximitymiles}
    else {if (proximitymetersenw > proximitymeterswne) {proximitymeterswne = proximitymiles};};

Comment: I meant: write in the question which is the issue or the target you want to achieve (simply "In Google Map v3 I need to get the radius in miles of my current map view.") and add an answer (not a comment) with the complete solution.

Comment: @TerranBrown, curious how you came up with the `0.000621371192` number. I ask because this is somewhat working for me, but it's a little bit off and it's kind of hard to debug why. I thought it might have to do with the Maps API thinking my map was a different size than the DOM is actually displaying it as, but even if I changed the height by, say 150px, the `sw` and `ne` bounds are still the same.

Comment: Heh, nevermind, I see that that's the meters to miles calculation :)

Comment: bounds.getNorthWest()? bounds.getSouthEast()? There are no such functions on the google.maps.LatLngBounds class...

Comment: But in case you need them:

                getBoundsNorthWest : function(bounds) {

      var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
      var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();

      return new google.maps.LatLng (ne.lat(), sw.lng());
  },

  getBoundsSouthEast : function(bounds) {

      var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
      var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();

      return new google.maps.LatLng (sw.lat(), ne.lng());
  }

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
// Watches for map bounds change - if so - set radius and refresh data Start
function setproximityfrommap() {
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525670/radius-of-viewable-region-in-google-maps-v3
    // Get Gmap radius / proximity start
    // First, determine the map bounds
    var bounds = map.getBounds();

    // Then the points
    var swPoint = bounds.getSouthWest();
    var nePoint = bounds.getNorthEast();

    // Now, each individual coordinate
    var swLat = swPoint.lat();
    var swLng = swPoint.lng();
    var neLat = nePoint.lat();
    var neLng = nePoint.lng();

    var proximitymeter = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(swPoint, nePoint);
    var proximitymiles = proximitymeter * 0.000621371192;
    proxmity = proximitymiles;
    console.log("Proxmity " + proximitymiles + " miles");
}
```